# How to add SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" in <wsse:security> header using python zeep library

Tags: python, xml, soap, x509, zeep

I want my XML request to look like this -

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
```

However the output I'm getting from zeep is like this -

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap-env:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
```

How can I include xmlns:wsu and SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" in the xml generated by zeep?

My  code is  -

```
import zeep as zp 
from lxml import etree
from zeep.wsse import BinarySignature
import xmlsec
from zeep.transports import Transport


client = zp.Client('http://locahost:8085/soap-server/gor/request/MasterData.wsdl',wsse=BinarySignature(key_file='private.pem',certfile='cert.pem', digest_method=xmlsec.constants.TransformSha256))

transport  = Transport()
factory = client.type_factory('ns0')

# product_type = client.get_type('ns0:PRODUCTMASTERDATA')
barcode = client.get_type('ns0:BARCODEDATA')(MPN_CAGE_BARCODE="test123")
description = client.get_type('ns0:DESCRIPTIONDATA')(PRDTXT='Test SKU', LANGU='EN')
dimensions = client.get_type('ns0:DIMENSIONDATA')(LAENG_LENGTH=10, BREIT_WIDTH= 10, HOEHE_HEIGHT= 10, MEABM_UNIT= 'INCH')
level_type = client.get_type('ns0:LEVELTYPEDATA')(QUANTITY=1,BARCODE_LIST=barcode, DIMENSION=dimensions, BRGEW_WEIGHT={'_value_1':"2",'GEWEI_TC_UNIT': "OUNCE"}, MEINS_LABEL='ITEM')
item_config = client.get_type('ns0:ITEMCONFIGDATA')(LEVEL_TYPE=level_type)
metadata = factory.METADATA(MESSAGEID='123456',CREA_DATE="2021-07-06+05:30",CREA_TIME="14:57:06.839+05:30", RECEIVERID="43567", SENDERID="89743894")
masterdata = factory.PRODUCTMASTERDATA(METADATA=metadata, DESCRIPTION=description, TAG_LIST={'CHARG_TAG_NAME':{'_value_1':"23223",'MANDATORY':'true'}}, ITEM_CONFIG=item_config, MATNR_PRODUCT_SKU='334423')
product_list = factory.PRODUCTLISTDATA(PRODUCT_MASTER=masterdata, LGNUM='12')

node = client.create_message(client.service, 'PRODUCT', PRODUCT_MASTER=masterdata, LGNUM='12')
x = etree.tostring(node)
print(x)
client.service.PRODUCT(PRODUCT_MASTER=masterdata, LGNUM='12')
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from lxml.etree import QName
from zeep.utils import detect_soap_env
from zeep.wsse.utils import get_security_header

soap_env = detect_soap_env(root_node)
security = get_security_header(envelope)
security.set(QName(soap_env, "mustUnderstand"), "1")
```